# Why is NODE_ENV not being set by my makefile?

Tags: node.js, makefile, environment-variables

This is my Makefile:

```
start:
    make start-prod

start-dev:
    @NODE_ENV=development
    make start-bare

start-prod:
    @NODE_ENV=production
    make start-bare

start-bare:
    node src/bootstrap

test:
    @NODE_ENV=test
    mocha --ignore-leaks $(shell find ./test -name \*test.js)

.PHONY: start start-dev start-prod start-bare test
```

When I run `make start-dev` then `process.env.NODE_ENV` equals `undefined`. Why is this so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside a makefile target, each line is a separate shell instance, so setting an environment variable in one won't transfer over to the other. Instead do something like:

```
start-prod:
    @NODE_ENV=production \
      make start-bare
```

or

```
start-prod:
    @NODE_ENV=production make start-bare
```

Comment: Do the separate shell instances run in parallel?

Comment: Tom, no they don't run in parallel. However, if you have a rule that depends on multiple other rules, and you're using the `-j`/`--jobs` switch, then those _will_ run in parallel.

Comment: You should mention that you can execute a target in the same shell isntance with `source`